# PHP, JSON not displaying correctly on delete

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="results.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="resultsDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The following JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    init();
}

var xmlhttp;
var intervalHandle;

function init() {   
    getAjaxData();
    intervalHandle = setInterval(getAjaxData, 2000);
}

function getAjaxData() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+. Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = showJSONData;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "results2Json.php", true); // GET results from DB
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function showJSONData() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        if (data.results.length > 0) { // Delete this line and it's closing brace, below, and the code does what expected
            var output = '<table border=1>';
            output += '<tr><th>Name</th></tr>';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                output += '<tr><td>' + data.results[i].name + '</td></tr>';
            }

            output += '</table>';
            document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = output;
        } //Closing brace
    }
}
```

And finally the following PHP:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"random");
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select name from random_name");

$rs = array();
while($rs[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // do nothing ;-)
}
mysqli_close($con);

unset($rs[count($rs)-1]);  //removes a null value
print("{ \"results\":" . json_encode($rs) . "}");
?>
```

all just pulling a single column from a DB, and automatically refreshing the results every 2 seconds. If I add to the DB, the results are refreshing fine. If I delete items from the DB all works fine also, until I attempt to delete the last item. This then remains on screen. I'm aware that if I take out the `if (data.results.length > 0)` line then the final item will delete OK but what I want to achieve is that the table header is not displayed either if the SQL query in the php file returns no results. Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Side note: that last line of your PHP code is bad practice, you should use `echo json_encode(array('results' => $rs));` so that your entire output is controlled by `json_encode`

Comment: @scrowler Thanks, I'll bare that in mind and change in my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no results in function showJSONData, your program has no output, so the final result does not update.  Change function showJSONData to

```
function showJSONData() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

        if (data.results.length > 0) { // Delete this line and it's closing brace, below, and the code does what expected
            var output = '<table border=1>';
            output += '<tr><th>Name</th></tr>';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                output += '<tr><td>' + data.results[i].name + '</td></tr>';
            }

            output += '</table>';
            document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = output;
        } //Closing brace

        else{
            document.getElementById("resultsDiv").innerHTML = "no results";
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's tidier than the answer above